# Не работает transition смены цвета при :hover в google chrome

Tags: svg, анимация, google-chrome

Имеется обычный `circle`

И так же имеется желание увидеть плавность смены `fill`, который назначены через переменные типа `var(--color)` при использовании в `use`

Про `shadow dom` знаю и по этому поводу объяснений не надо а хочу увидеть способ плавной смены `fill`

В Firefox отрабатывает шикарно и больше **нигде**...

Сам пример вопроса:

```css
svg {
  --color: red;
}

circle {
  transition: 0.34s linear;
}

svg:hover {
  --color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="c">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="var(--color)">
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg width="50px"><use xlink:href="#c" /></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#icon" x="0" y="0" class="icon"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получилось менять цвет у `<use`, если это интересно..

```css
svg {
  --color: red;
}

use {
  transition: 0.34s linear;
  fill : var(--color);
}

svg:hover {
  --color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="c">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg width="50px"><use xlink:href="#c" /></svg>
```

Comment: а я не допетрил что то ...офигеть

Comment: Хм.. А почему в svg переменные анимируются? В html же нет, если registerProperty не вызвать.

Comment: @Qwertiy в хроме много странностей, сайд-эффекты реализации)

Answer (score 3):

```js
CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--color', 
  syntax: '<color>', 
  initialValue: 'transparent',
  inherits: true,
})
```

```css
svg {
  --color: red;
  transition: --color 0.34s linear;
}

svg:hover {
  --color: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="c">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="var(--color)">
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg width="50px"><use xlink:href="#c" /></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#icon" x="0" y="0" class="icon"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: js не надо сюда ...плиз

Comment: в этом случае анимация не робит в FF

Comment: @MaximLensky, его потом о-ccs'ят: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55037441/4928642

Comment: кстати сейчас должен настоящий источник этого вопроса появится - не вздумайте его дубликатом пометить

Comment: @MaximLensky, FF скоро подтянется: https://ishoudinireadyyet.com/ - Properties & Values API - In Development.

Comment: хотя если честно я не вижу смысла усложнять когда можно всё это делать в css без всяких var

Comment: @MaximLensky, так ты ж про var спросил, или нет? А так-то можно и без var.

Comment: да я спросил - только вопрос не мой - я его на toster увидел -